# Small java program prints invisible newline?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, newline, user-input, system.out

I'm doing an assignment and I am done. This is a simple program that prints out pyramids of chars. However, I can't figure out why the program prints a newline when I never specified it with some input, even if it's meant to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCdI9.png 
Why do I have to have an extra newline when printing the pyramid upside down? Where is the newline printed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test23 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    boolean state = true;

    String messageL = "Length: ";
    String messageD = "Position: ";
    String messageS = "Shutdown!";

    while(state) {
        int limit = 0;
        int degree;

        System.out.print(messageL);
        int length  = input.nextInt();

        while ((length < 1 && length == -1) || length > 26) {

            if (length == -1 ) {
                System.out.println(messageS + "\n");
                state = false;
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.print(messageL);
                length  = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        if (!state)
            break;
        System.out.print(messageD);
        degree = input.nextInt();

        while((degree > 1) || (degree < 0)) {
            System.out.print(messageD);
            degree = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (degree == 0) 
            //No newline is needed here for some reason.
            length++;

        else if (degree == 1) 
            limit = length;
            //New line here for the pyramids to print symmetrically.
            //System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++) {
                char letter = (char)(counter + 'A');
                System.out.print(letter);
            }

            if (degree == 0) 
                limit++;

            else if (degree == 1) 
                limit--;

            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(messageS + "\n");` `System.out.println("");` `System.out.println("");`

Comment: System.out.println(messageS + "\n") is only used when the program is shutting down. If I remove the first print, it won't print a pyramid. If I remove the second, it doesn't make a difference.  @Oleg

Comment: hint: What happens with your most inner loop when your input is 0? You should really read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I see the problem now, the most inner loop doesn't run the first time, so it prints out a newline instead? Anyway, thank you for the article. @Oleg

Comment: Yes, exactly. Please learn how to debug and solve those kind of issues. This is a skill you must learn if you plan on becoming a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

> Small java program prints invisible newline?

In your program the last **System.out.println("");** causes an extra line at the end of your program, i.e `while(state)` is **true** at the end, So either you comment the print statement or make your `state=false` at end.

```
while(state) {    
    ... 
    System.out.println(""); 
}
```

Comment: I removed it, the problem persists. @ Soumya Das

Comment: Take a look at all such prints. Temporarily enter a word for all prints, a different one for every print. By that you directly see which print statement is responsible for your last undesired print.

Comment: Comment the last System.out.println(""); You'll get no extra line
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A

Answer (score 0):

The most inner loop won't run if the input is 0. `limit` will be 0, and hence the loop condition is false. As of this it will print en empty line, proceeding to add `1` too `limit` and *then* print chars.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    for (int counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++) {
        char letter = (char)(counter + 'A');
```